# Cookies not working in IE or Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies

I have a Rails 3.2.8 and Ruby 1.9.3 app.

I'm trying to set a cookie like so:

```
cookies['role'] = {
      :value => params['commit'],
      :expires => Time.now + 30.days,
  }
```

It works fine in chrome, but IE and Firefox seem to be completely ignoring this. On IE I turned my privacy settings off to allow all cookies, and still nothing. My sub domain does NOT have underscores in it which is about the only solution I could find relating to my problem.

Domain is: projects.mikksdesign.com

just a simple little app. Once you select either project manager, or developer, it should save a cookie with role set to "pm" or "dev". Not happening though...

Any ideas would be awesome!

Thanks

Comment: A note not related to your Problem:
If your app is accessible via Internet, you should *REALLY* upgrade your Rails-version to the latest one (3.2.12 for 3.2.x branch). During the last 2 months, there were several security issues.

Comment: Strange. This should work. You could try adding ":domain => :all" to see if that fixes it, but I doubt it will.

Comment: @Deradon - That is really good info, I will do that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, well it turns out this is NOT related to the cookie, but instead related to the form submit. I had two submit buttons, each with a unique value. In the controller it was looking for param['commit'], and setting the cookie value based on that commit. Don't ask me why this was not cross browser, but turns out, I only got this to work in Chrome. I changed the way I was doing things to a route based param, and just linked the images that way instead. no more cookie problems!

So I guess I jumped the gun. The cookie was not setting because it was never getting into the block to set it (if params['commit'])

thanks for the help guys!